# How to loop DOM elements and store as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping, domdocument

I'm getting a data via scrapping.
The data source is a table and I need to get the data for every (tr).

The table has 3 (td) which is:

- title
- date
- link

Here is the code that I use:

```
$data = array();
$counter = 1;
$index = 0;

foreach($html->find('#middle table tr td') as $source){

    $dont_include = array(
        '<td>CONTAIN TEXT THAT I DONT WNAT TO INCLUDE IN HERE</td>'
    );

    if (!in_array($source->outertext, $dont_include)) {

        // IF IT CONTAIN LINK THEN GET IT LINK
        // THE SOURCE DATA FOR LINK IS SOMETHING LIKE 
        // <td><a href="">xx</a></td>
        if(strstr($source->innertext, 'http://')){

               $a = new SimpleXMLElement($source->innertext);

               $the_link = (string) $a['href'][0];
               $data[$index] = array('link' => $the_link);;
        }else{
            if ($counter==2) {
                $data[$index] = array('title' => $source->innertext);
            }else{
                $data[$index] = array('date' => $source->innertext);
                $counter = 0;
                $index++;
            }
        }
    }
    $counter++;
}

print_r($data);
```

The problem :
How can I store the these values in an array using this structure:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [title] => ""
        [date] => ""
        [link] => ""
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [title] => ""
        [date] => ""
        [link] => ""
    )
    ...
)
```

Update, here is the source structure :

```
    <!-- THIS IS THE SOURCE , AT THE TOP HERE CONTAIN TD THAT I DONT WANT -->
    <td>title</td>
    <td class="ac">date</td>
    <td width="190"><a href="i need this link" target="_blank">filename , i dont need the file name</a>
    </td>
<td>title</td>
    <td class="ac">date</td>
    <td width="190"><a href="i need this link" target="_blank">filename , i dont need the file name</a>
    </td>
<td>title</td>
    <td class="ac">date</td>
    <td width="190"><a href="i need this link" target="_blank">filename , i dont need the file name</a>
    </td>
<td>title</td>
    <td class="ac">date</td>
    <td width="190"><a href="i need this link" target="_blank">filename , i dont need the file name</a>
    </td>
```

Comment: `title`,`date`,`link` is your td data am i right?

Comment: `tr` may contains either `td` or `th`

Comment: Can you please describe your issue in detail..

Comment: check below my answer it will solve your problem or get any error

Comment: @taek Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Do not EVER use `strstr()` to check the existence of a string in a string.  The PHP manual explicitly says so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of loop through `td` I suggest you to loop through `tr` so that you can create your array. Try this

```
$rowData = array();

foreach ($html->find('#middle table tr') as $rows) {
    $cellData = array();

    $cellData['title'] = $rows->children(0)->innertext;
    $cellData['date'] = $rows->children(1)->innertext;
    $cellData['link'] = $rows->children(2)->innertext;

    $rowData[] = $cellData;
}
print_r($rowData);
```

Comment: What is the reason for down vote? I have test this and its working properly

Comment: also Not my down vote , i have provided the source data in the question :)

Comment: @B.Desai This is the answer Thanks !

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for trying to help :)